# I can't seem to paint while using weight paint for character rigging

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting, rigify

Title says it all. I can't paint no matter what I press and whatever settings I change, despite being in the right mode and having selected the corresponding bone.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

turn face selection masking off. (the blue one means it's on)

[image]